# Mac Mini - HDMI Monitor - No display

Tags: mac, display, hdmi

Case 1: Mac Mini to CRT Monitor via 'thunderbolt' - Proper Display - No Problem

Case 2: Mac Mini to CRT monitor and HDMI monitor - Dual Display - No Problem

**Case 3: Mac Mini to HDMI Monitor - No Display - Problem**

The mac mini is connected to CRT monitor through 'thunderbolt' via an adaptor and it works fine.

I wanted to connect the HDMI Monitor (Acer) to the Mac Mini. Mac mini has HDMI to DVI adaptor cable. But my Acer monitor has direct HDMI port.

So I connected the Acer HDMI port to the Mac mini. Now both the monitor are ON and works as 'dual monitor'.

But, with only Acer HDMI, monitor says 'No signal'. It is totally dependent on Thunderbolt - CRT monitor.

How to use **only** the **'Acer HDMI monitor' with 'Mac mini'** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This above mentioned issue got resolved, by just reverse connecting the HDMI cable.
The monitor had double ports which accommodates HDMI cable in both ends.

So 'Case 3' also displays the monitor contents now.